# Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15 is not working in ajax javascript responce

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I use different languages in my online examination web application, first it get loaded well, but when i move to 2nd question iam sending request to ajax with question id, in response ajax gives question details, but in db these questions are in special characters and i get same special character in response. but i use there some below encoding function in ajax file also in php file.

---

*questions.php - PHP file*

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15');
    ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
    include '../inc_classes.php';

    if((time()-$_SESSION['last_login_time'])>900)
        $_SESSION['last_login_time']="";
    else
        $_SESSION['last_login_time']=time();

    $select_question_last = " select question_title from question where question_id='".$question_id."'" ;
        $ptrs_last_que = mysql_query($select_question_last) ;
        $i=0 ;
        while($data_ptr_last_que = mysql_fetch_array($ptrs_last_que))
        {
            echo $question_title = stripslashes($data_ptr_last_que['question_title']);
        }
?>
```

---

*show_ques.php - AJAX file*

```
$.ajax({
    url: url2,
    type: "get",
    contentType: "text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-15",
    data: paramss,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        //alert(html)
        if (html.trim() == 'logout') {
            alert('You can not attempt exam any more. please contact your school.!');
            document.location.href = 'index.php?action=<?php echo base64_encode('
            logout '); ?>';
        } else
            $("#question_div").html(html);
        check_remaining()
    }

});
```

Comment: just change `type:get` to `post` and then can you please check?

Comment: ok thanks i will check.. but is it matter because when i print it show same special character

Comment: In wich part of the code you see the problem?

Comment: in ajax show_ques.php..also when i use post method iam not getting some parameters value

Comment: charset is not working on ajax page.. it returns special characters in response